# Confusion in use of templates and structs in c++

Tags: c++

I was actually, trying to understand a piece of code in c++ and came accross this snippet, here is the Packet being made a new datatype? what exactly are "homeDeliv" and "pickUp". Are they being defined here or are they defined somewhere else, just used here?

I'm new to C++ syntax. Plese help...

```
template< typename Pac > struct Packets;
  template<> struct Packets< homeDeliv > { static const unsigned ID = 0; };
  template<> struct Packets< pickUp > { static const unsigned ID = 1; };
```

Comment: They (`homeDeliv`, `pickUp`) are defined somewhere else.

Comment: Templates are *NOT* OOP. Repeat after me: templates are nowhere near OOP. The mere fact you can create polymorphic types using templates is irrelevant.

Comment: @Griwes, thanks and point noted ... i was just considering that template keyword is used in many contexts related to OOP like overloading etc. So i thought this may be similar

Comment: In fact, templates may often collide with OOP design, one easy example being that you may not separate declaration from implementation

Comment: @nijansen More generally: templates provide a common implementation for different interfaces; OO is usually about providing different implementations for a common interface.

Comment: @nijansen And of course, you can (and usually will) separate declaration from implementation with templates.  Both, of course, have to be included in C++ (C++ templates are a bit broken in this regard), but they can (and usually should) be in separate files.

Comment: @JamesKanze Hey, that's really well put, I'll quote that from now on; thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are explicit specializations of the template `Packets`.

Whenever you use a `Packets< homeDeliv >`, that implementation will be used.

Non-explicit specializations use the default template.

```
struct homeDeliv {};
struct foo {};
template< typename Pac > struct Packets { static const unsigned ID = 42; } ;
template<> struct Packets< homeDeliv > { static const unsigned ID = 0; };

//.....
Packets<homeDeliv> x;
assert ( x.ID == 0 );

Packets<foo> y;
assert ( y.ID == 42 );

Packets<int> z;
assert ( z.ID == 42 );
```

Answer (score 2):

These are template specializations. `homeDeliv` and `pickUp` are types, declared elsewhere. For example,

```
template<> struct Packets<int> { static const unsigned ID = 42; };
```

then

```
std::cout << Packets<int>::ID << "\n"; // prints 42.
```

Comment: Dude... 42... really? :D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I got it from my own PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

These are template specializations.

**what exactly are "homeDeliv" and "pickUp"**

They are user-defined data types or a `typedef`.

**Are they being defined here**

No, they are not defined here. They must have been defined somewhere else in the code. They are used here to create template specializations of `Packets`

Answer (score 0):

It is a template specialization and homeDeliv as pickUp are both types.

Answer (score 0):

This is a template specialization. It is often used this way if you want to provide functionality only for given types. In this case `homeDeliv` and `pickUp` have to be already defined somewhere else, then:

```
template <typename> struct X; // incomplete type will cause error on instantiation
template <> struct X<int> { /* whatever */ }; // now X<int> is valid, but all other
                                              // still cause compilation errors
```